# How to continously update the background in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a very simple setup. I have a loop that just goes through x values. I want the user to decide whether they wish to go through the loop again. Within the loop, there are 2 images that pop up depending on the condition of x. On the first iteration, I can go through the loop, and the images pop up properly, however on subsequent iterations, the Tkinter window no longer updates.

I know about `after()`, but I'm trying to understand why the below doesn't work (nothing has changed between the 1st iteration to the 2nd, so why doesn't it work anymore?)

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

Images='mountain.jpg'
class Example(Frame):
    global Images
    def __init__(self, master, *pargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *pargs)



        self.image = Image.open(Images)
        self.img_copy= self.image.copy()


        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.background = Label(self, image=self.background_image)
        self.background.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        self.background.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

    def _resize_image(self,event):

        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height

        self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image =  self.background_image)

def main(e):
    global Images
    x=0
    root.update_idletasks()
    while x<10000900:
        x+=1
        if x == 50:
            Images='mountain.jpg'
            e.destroy()
            e = Example(root)
            e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
            root.update_idletasks()

        if x == 5000000:
            Images='greencar.jpg'
            e.destroy()
            e = Example(root)
            e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
            root.update_idletasks()


def loop(e):
    while True:
        question=input('would you like to go again?')
        if question == 'n':
            break
        main(e)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')
e = Example(root)
e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
loop(e)
root.destroy()
root.mainloop()
```

Edit: To address the implementation of the comments:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import messagebox as mb


Images='mountain.jpg'
class Example(Frame):
    global Images
    def __init__(self, master, *pargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *pargs)



        self.image = Image.open(Images)
        self.img_copy= self.image.copy()


        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.background = Label(self, image=self.background_image)
        self.background.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        self.background.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

    def _resize_image(self,event):

        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height

        self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image =  self.background_image)

def main():
    global Images
    e = Example(root)
    e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
    x=0
    while x<10000900:
        x+=1
        if x == 50:
            Images='mountain.jpg'
            e.destroy()
            e = Example(root)
            e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
            root.update_idletasks()

        if x == 5000000:
            Images='greencar.jpg'
            e.destroy()
            e = Example(root)
            e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
            root.update_idletasks()
    return e


def loop():
    while True:
        res=mb.askquestion('Replay', 'Would you like to play another round?')
        if res == 'yes' :
            e = main()
        else :
            root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')
loop()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Every time you call `main()`, `e` is the very same instance of `Example` - the one you created first, and destroyed first.  So the second time through the loop, `main()` has no reference to the current instance of `Example`, and is therefore unable to destroy it - instead, it tries to stuff a new instance into the window along with the current instance (the last one created on the first call to `main()`).  And there's simply no room for it, as the Label occupies the whole window.

Comment: Ah, so would a possible solution be to add the `e=Example(root)` and `pack` underneath the `While True` of `loop()` ? This way `e` is constantly remade, and `main(e)` always has an instance of `e` to destroy.

Comment: You can return `e` from `main()` and then use `e = main(e)` inside `loop()`.  Also don't use `input()` in GUI application, use `tkinter.messagebox.askyesno()` instead.

Comment: Hmm this didn't seem to work either. Also, for some reason using `tkinter.messagebox.` causes it to be asked twice when trying to quit (it'll open up 2 windows). I've added an edit to demonstrate how I've implemented your suggestion.

Comment: @acw1668 sorry forgot to tag you in my reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you have returned `e` from `main()`, but you didn't pass it back to `main()` in next loop.  Below are modified `main()` and `loop()`:

```
def main(e):
    global Images
    x=0
    while x<10000900:
        x+=1
        if x == 50:
            e.destroy()
            Images='images/nier-a2.png'
            e = Example(root)
            e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
            root.update()

        if x == 5000000:
            e.destroy()
            Images='images/nier-a2_clicked.png'
            e = Example(root)
            e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
            root.update()
    return e

def loop():
    e = Example(root)
    e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
    root.update()
    while True:
        e = main(e)
        if mb.askquestion('Replay', 'Would you like to play another round?') != 'yes':
            break

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')
loop()
# you should not call `root.mainloop()` as `loop()` is used
#root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh I see, I wasn't calling in the variable e that we were defining in loop, in main.